# How do I access the source level definition of classes at runtime?

Tags: ios, xcode, clang, objective-c-runtime, f-script

How do I access the Objective-C class interface defanition that is collected from headers at (pre or actual) compile time so I can provide introspection that is true to the defined public interface.

Problem: F-Script, SuperDB, IKBClassBrowser, CBIntrospection use the class_copyPropertyList() family of functions to introspect objects at run time. While powerful, there are drawbacks…

1. the runtime has no concept of private and public… everything is
   returned
2. I can not see a reliable way to access the to the ObjC types of
   method arguments and returns

Goal: I am researching a iOS app to help teach coding via a live / immediate development environment (similar to SmallTalk, F-Script, SuperDB, IKBClassBrowser, CBIntrospection). I want users to introspect objects, send messages, create new objects, and build and run code via a VM. **But I want to limit the functionality to public functions** (there is no way Apple would approve the app otherwise) and **I want to have access to types so I limit so users can only pass legal objects.**

My hope is that there is some way to access **Clang** or the **symbol file** to pull this information in way I can **use it at runtime**. It does not have to be fully automated (I will probably want to limit functionality in some ways)

Answer (score 1):

You're encountering one of the distinguishing characteristics of Objective-C: There is no such thing as private or public API. There's only documented API vs. undocumented API. You can call any method on any object at any time, regardless of whether it appears in a header file. Public/private distinctions exist only for the compiler; at run time, they don't exist, and there's no way to reverse the process and discern what the header files might have said.

Comment: I don’t think you have understood my question - I want to build a model of the public interface which is defined in the source code and use that at run time to limit what I expose to the user. I speculate that there are many ways this could be done. I could, for example, take each class one at a time and build my own data structure from it’s public interface - but I speculate there is away to parse the data the compiler generates at compile time to do this